# Issues using PHP simplexml_load_file to parse a podcast feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml, podcast

I was using some code I knocked up to parse some podcast feeds and only get the first episode and in the past week, presumably due to changes in the feeds, it simply stopped working...

The code is as follows and I've tried many things after reading the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to get it working again but I seem to be going down a rabbit hole of making things worse...

Anyone able to help?
Thank you

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
$output = '<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">';
/* IGN */
$xmlIGN = simplexml_load_file('https://api.spokenlayer.com/feed/channel/ign-podcasts-ext/3c9929b72538c12bd92ac6762f8d798b9d4e8cdca7692ea74f466061d01816cb');
$IGN = ($xmlIGN->channel->item[0]);
print_r ($output);
print_r ('<channel>');
print_r ($IGN->asXML());
print_r ('</channel></rss>');
?>
```

After throwing in some test tags it appears to be erroring at the simplexml_load_file but uncertain why...

Edit: Added picture of active PHP extensions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peyf8.png)

Comment: Your code works on my local server. Maybe try to output all errors. Try to change `https://api.spokenlayer.com` to `http://api.spokenlayer.com`. check if "PHP SimpleXML" is installed (normally is a core PHP library, it should be there).

Comment: _"After throwing in some test tags it appears to be erroring at the simplexml_load_file but uncertain why"_ - Please share more info. It's good that you've added some debugging, but we can't see your results so we can't really know where or how it fails for you. We need details. Have you also checked the web servers error log to see if there are any errors/warnings in there that can help?

Comment: @M.Eriksson the error i get when trying to render is:

> This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 131: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I threw in some text simply to print and before each process call and it failed before the $IGN->asXML() line

@B

Comment: @Bl457Xor same issue with http vs https
I've not changed anything PHP on my server but maybe my hoster has - will check... but SimpleXML worked last week!

Comment: Added image of active extensions

Comment: GOT IT!
While digging around the options in my PHP setup there was a setting called 
*allow_url_fopen* which was disabled

I've never touched this before, but seems to have been turned off at some point - causing the issue